# Angular 2 and Webpack lazy loading

Tags: angular, webpack

I am surely missing something very fundamental here. I am developing an Angular 2 app where the user logs in. After login the user will be able to access secured components that are only visible to logged in users. How can i seperate Webpack to first serve the login screen and only after a succesfull login the rest?

In [angular2-authentication-sample](https://github.com/auth0-blog/angular2-authentication-sample) in chrome dev tools I can see all the source code before logged in. Even the source code of the pages that are visible only after login.

So my question is:

- What is the right way to restrict users of having an access to source code of the section that is behind a login screen.

Comment: Why does it matter if they can see the JS source code? It shouldn't contain any data.

Comment: True, the actual data is secured by JWT. But still i believe there should be a way to keep html code of the login secured pages hidden from the users that are not having credentials to login.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this medium post](https://medium.com/@daviddentoom/angular-2-lazy-loading-with-webpack-d25fe71c29c1#.wuj3cycnr) using angular2 router *lazy loading* and webpack *angular2-router-loader*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use power of dynamically loaded chunks. For example imagine this mockup of routing:

```js
switch(routeName) {
  case 'home':
    const homePage = require('homePage');
    homePage();  
    break;
  case 'contact':
    const contactPage = require('contactPage');
    contactPage(); 
    break;
  case 'dashboard':                             // <-- this should be protected
    const dashboardPage = require('dashboardPage');
    dashboardPage(); 
    break;
  case 'informationForLoggedUser':               // <-- this should be protected
    const informationForLoggedUserPage = require('informationForLoggedUserPage');
    informationForLoggedUserPage(); 
    break;
};
```

In above example all your routes will be downloaded in single `bundle.js` file. To change that you can use power of [`require.ensure`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html). Wrap your protected routes in `require.ensure` with [3rd parameter](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#named-chunks) naming this chunk as `protected` (this name can be different - it's just example).

```js
switch(routeName) {
  case 'home':
    const homePage = require('homePage');
    homePage();  
    break;
  case 'contact':
    const contactPage = require('contactPage');
    contactPage(); 
    break;
  case 'dashboard':                             // <-- this will be protected
    require.ensure([], () => {
      const dashboardPage = require('dashboardPage');
      dashboardPage(); 
    }, 'protected');
    break;
  case 'informationForLoggedUser':               // <-- this will be protected
    require.ensure([], () => {
      const informationForLoggedUserPage = require('informationForLoggedUserPage');
      informationForLoggedUserPage(); 
    }, 'protected');
    break;
};
```

In your `webpack.config.js` if you will have this configuration:

```js
entry: path.resolve('src', 'main.js'),
output: {
  path: path.resolve('build'),
  filename: '[name].js',       // <-- this is important
  publicPath: '/'
},
```

The webpack will produce this files:

```
main.js
1.protected.js
```

Now you must provide on your own **protection on the backed - to not send `*.protected.js` file for not authenticated users**.

Comment: Does this actually work with the routing on current Angular 2 RC4?

Comment: My answer is framework agnostic. If properly applied it should work with: angular / angular 2 / react / ember / or what you prefer.

Comment: Seems tricky with Angular 2 as the routes has to be given as an array of objects that will be all loaded at the init and AsyncRoute is not there anymore. [Actual route example](https://github.com/auth0-blog/angular2-authentication-sample/blob/master/src/app.routes.ts)

Comment: You can use `require.ensure` on `Home` component level (I assume that `Home` component should be available after authentication).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want all of your code to be on the client side, you can use something like:

[Angular Universal](https://universal.angular.io/)

[Angular Universal starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter)

[Angular Universal Github page](https://github.com/angular/universal)

Comment: Thanks, but is this really the only/best way to keep my html code hidden? I was expecting there to be a way to lazy load the pieces of the html code once the template is needed.

Comment: As long the data is on the server ,the client will not see it.The same applies to HTML and everything in it. Ask the server to load the home page after log in.  You can use any server you like.